# Bash program to calculate point locations with distances

Tags: bash, calculator, bc

So, I am trying to write a bash program to calculate the points I need for rendering an image. I need to calculate various points in an array. The points for A should be in the same direction that they travel from the center, but with a specific distance as defined in the script. The output points for B should be relative to their A counterparts. (Ex: The first output in point B should have the X equal to the X output for point A -12, while the Y should be equal to the Y output for point A +8)

To make things more clear, I am trying to use ImageMagick to draw lines on the edge of a circle, and I need to map points A to tbe edge of the circle and draw the lines to B. Here is the test code sample I am working on:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Define points
center='512,423'
pointa=( '256,192' '128,244' '192,192' '256,512' '384,192' )
pointb=( '244,200' '111,222' '200,185' '267,397' '333,234' )

  calp(){ for ((i=0;i<${#pointa[@]};i++));do 
              abasex="`echo "${pointa[$i]}"|cut -d',' -f1`"
              abasey="`echo "${pointa[$i]}"|cut -d',' -f2`"
              bbasex="`echo "${pointb[$i]}"|cut -d',' -f1`"
              bbasey="`echo "${pointb[$i]}"|cut -d',' -f2`"
              boffsx="`echo "$bbasex-$abasex"|bc`"
              boffsy="`echo "$bbasey-$abasey"|bc`"
              #//Calculation code for point A goes here\\#
              bx="`echo "$ax+$boffsx"|sed 's/+-/-/g'|bc`"
              by="`echo "$ay+$boffsy"|sed 's/+-/-/g'|bc`"
              calcda="$ax,$ay";calcdb="$bx,$by"

              printf "Line $i) A:$calcda B:$calcdb D:$dist"
            done;};

for dist in {30..70};do calp;done
```

To clarify, I want to translate each point in point A in the same direction that it is from `$center` to match each distance in `$dist`, and apply the same translation to the corresponding point B, then return the X and Y values of points A and B, as well as the distance given. A calculation guide can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175896/finding-a-point-along-a-line-a-certain-distance-away-from-another-point).

Comment: Sorry, I am confused about what you are trying to do. Can you show us a example or diagram of what it should look like?

Comment: @fmw42 Sometimes I have trouble explaining things, but I added an example from another page and tried to clarify it.

Comment: But I do not understand the relationship between pointsA and pointsB. You have a center point and say pointsA. Are you trying to find pointsB that lie on a line from the center to pointsA and then draw a line from pointsA to pointsB of certain distances? If not, then what are your pointsB?  And why do you want multiple distances? Are they to be drawn on different images or the same image? If the same image, then the longer ones will cover the shorter ones.  Please clarify or make a drawing showing what you want.

Comment: @fmw42 I tried to clarify it. Basically I want to relocate point A so it's in the same direction from the center but with the given distance, and apply the same translation to point B, then return the values.

Comment: Sorry, I still do not understand. I understand about redrawing pointA at a new location some distance from its old position along a line from the center. But I do not understand what you want to do with pointB. Do you want it to be shifted in parallel to how pointA was shifted?  Do you want lines to be drawn from old pointA to new pointA and similarly for old pointB and new pointB. Or do you want a line between the two new pointA and pointB.  If you could make a drawing and provide that, it would be most helpful to understand what you want to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still trying to understand your question and work on an answer. So far, I have simplified and removed a load of unnecessary extra processes running `bc`, `cut` and stuff to use the much faster internal `bash` mechanisms.

I am using Pontio's method [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2109383):

```
#!/bin/bash

#Define points
center='512,423'
pointa=( '256,192' '128,244' '192,192' '256,512' '384,192' )
pointb=( '244,200' '111,222' '200,185' '267,397' '333,234' )

calp(){
   # Extract x,y of centre
   xa=${center/,*/}
   ya=${center/*,/}
   echo "dist:$dist, xa:$xa, ya:$ya"

   for ((i=0;i<${#pointa[@]};i++));do 
      xb=${pointa[$i]/,*/}       # remove comma and everything after
      yb=${pointa[$i]/*,/}       # remove everything up to and including comma
      ((dx=xa-xb))
      ((dy=ya-yb))
      D=$( bc <<< "scale=5;sqrt($dx*$dx+$dy*$dy)")
      xc=$(bc <<< "scale=0;$xa - ($dist*$dx)/$D")      # scale=0 to force integer result
      yc=$(bc <<< "scale=0;$ya - ($dist*$dy)/$D")      # scale=0 to force integer result
      # Now get the x and y translation
      ((xtrans=xc-xb))
      ((ytrans=yc-yb))
      # Get x,y of other set
      xother=${pointb[$i]/,*/}       # remove comma and everything after
      yother=${pointb[$i]/*,/}       # remove everything up to and including comma
      # Apply same translation
      ((xother=xother+xtrans))
      ((yother=yother+ytrans))
      echo "   i:$i xb:$xb, yb:$yb, D:$D, xc:$xc, yc:$yc, xtrans:$xtrans, ytrans:$ytrans, xother:$xother, yother:$yother"
   done
}

for dist in {30..70};do
  calp
done
```

Here is the output I get:

```
dist:30, xa:512, ya:423
   i:0 xb:256, yb:192, D:344.81444, xc:490, yc:403, xtrans:234, ytrans:211, xother:478, yother:411
   i:1 xb:128, yb:244, D:423.67086, xc:485, yc:411, xtrans:357, ytrans:167, xother:468, yother:389
   i:2 xb:192, yb:192, D:394.66568, xc:488, yc:406, xtrans:296, ytrans:214, xother:496, yother:399
   i:3 xb:256, yb:512, D:271.02951, xc:484, yc:432, xtrans:228, ytrans:-80, xother:495, yother:317
   i:4 xb:384, yb:192, D:264.09278, xc:498, yc:397, xtrans:114, ytrans:205, xother:447, yother:439
dist:31, xa:512, ya:423
   i:0 xb:256, yb:192, D:344.81444, xc:489, yc:403, xtrans:233, ytrans:211, xother:477, yother:411
   i:1 xb:128, yb:244, D:423.67086, xc:484, yc:410, xtrans:356, ytrans:166, xother:467, yother:388
   i:2 xb:192, yb:192, D:394.66568, xc:487, yc:405, xtrans:295, ytrans:213, xother:495, yother:398
   i:3 xb:256, yb:512, D:271.02951, xc:483, yc:433, xtrans:227, ytrans:-79, xother:494, yother:318
   i:4 xb:384, yb:192, D:264.09278, xc:497, yc:396, xtrans:113, ytrans:204, xother:446, yother:438
dist:32, xa:512, ya:423
   i:0 xb:256, yb:192, D:344.81444, xc:489, yc:402, xtrans:233, ytrans:210, xother:477, yother:410
   i:1 xb:128, yb:244, D:423.67086, xc:483, yc:410, xtrans:355, ytrans:166, xother:466, yother:388
   i:2 xb:192, yb:192, D:394.66568, xc:487, yc:405, xtrans:295, ytrans:213, xother:495, yother:398
   i:3 xb:256, yb:512, D:271.02951, xc:482, yc:433, xtrans:226, ytrans:-79, xother:493, yother:318
   i:4 xb:384, yb:192, D:264.09278, xc:497, yc:396, xtrans:113, ytrans:204, xother:446, yother:438
dist:33, xa:512, ya:423
   i:0 xb:256, yb:192, D:344.81444, xc:488, yc:401, xtrans:232, ytrans:209, xother:476, yother:409
   i:1 xb:128, yb:244, D:423.67086, xc:483, yc:410, xtrans:355, ytrans:166, xother:466, yother:388
   i:2 xb:192, yb:192, D:394.66568, xc:486, yc:404, xtrans:294, ytrans:212, xother:494, yother:397
   i:3 xb:256, yb:512, D:271.02951, xc:481, yc:433, xtrans:225, ytrans:-79, xother:492, yother:318
   i:4 xb:384, yb:192, D:264.09278, xc:497, yc:395, xtrans:113, ytrans:203, xother:446, yother:437
dist:34, xa:512, ya:423
   i:0 xb:256, yb:192, D:344.81444, xc:487, yc:401, xtrans:231, ytrans:209, xother:475, yother:409
   i:1 xb:128, yb:244, D:423.67086, xc:482, yc:409, xtrans:354, ytrans:165, xother:465, yother:387
   i:2 xb:192, yb:192, D:394.66568, xc:485, yc:404, xtrans:293, ytrans:212, xother:493, yother:397
   i:3 xb:256, yb:512, D:271.02951, xc:480, yc:434, xtrans:224, ytrans:-78, xother:491, yother:319
   i:4 xb:384, yb:192, D:264.09278, xc:496, yc:394, xtrans:112, ytrans:202, xother:445, yother:436
dist:35, xa:512, ya:423
   i:0 xb:256, yb:192, D:344.81444, xc:487, yc:400, xtrans:231, ytrans:208, xother:475, yother:408
   i:1 xb:128, yb:244, D:423.67086, xc:481, yc:409, xtrans:353, ytrans:165, xother:464, yother:387
   i:2 xb:192, yb:192, D:394.66568, xc:484, yc:403, xtrans:292, ytrans:211, xother:492, yother:396
   i:3 xb:256, yb:512, D:271.02951, xc:479, yc:434, xtrans:223, ytrans:-78, xother:490, yother:319
   i:4 xb:384, yb:192, D:264.09278, xc:496, yc:393, xtrans:112, ytrans:201, xother:445, yother:435
dist:36, xa:512, ya:423
   i:0 xb:256, yb:192, D:344.81444, xc:486, yc:399, xtrans:230, ytrans:207, xother:474, yother:407
   i:1 xb:128, yb:244, D:423.67086, xc:480, yc:408, xtrans:352, ytrans:164, xother:463, yother:386
   i:2 xb:192, yb:192, D:394.66568, xc:483, yc:402, xtrans:291, ytrans:210, xother:491, yother:395
   i:3 xb:256, yb:512, D:271.02951, xc:478, yc:434, xtrans:222, ytrans:-78, xother:489, yother:319
   i:4 xb:384, yb:192, D:264.09278, xc:495, yc:392, xtrans:111, ytrans:200, xother:444, yother:434
dist:37, xa:512, ya:423
   i:0 xb:256, yb:192, D:344.81444, xc:485, yc:399, xtrans:229, ytrans:207, xother:473, yother:407
   i:1 xb:128, yb:244, D:423.67086, xc:479, yc:408, xtrans:351, ytrans:164, xother:462, yother:386
   i:2 xb:192, yb:192, D:394.66568, xc:482, yc:402, xtrans:290, ytrans:210, xother:490, yother:395
   i:3 xb:256, yb:512, D:271.02951, xc:478, yc:435, xtrans:222, ytrans:-77, xother:489, yother:320
   i:4 xb:384, yb:192, D:264.09278, xc:495, yc:391, xtrans:111, ytrans:199, xother:444, yother:433
dist:38, xa:512, ya:423
   i:0 xb:256, yb:192, D:344.81444, xc:484, yc:398, xtrans:228, ytrans:206, xother:472, yother:406
   i:1 xb:128, yb:244, D:423.67086, xc:478, yc:407, xtrans:350, ytrans:163, xother:461, yother:385
   i:2 xb:192, yb:192, D:394.66568, xc:482, yc:401, xtrans:290, ytrans:209, xother:490, yother:394
   i:3 xb:256, yb:512, D:271.02951, xc:477, yc:435, xtrans:221, ytrans:-77, xother:488, yother:320
   i:4 xb:384, yb:192, D:264.09278, xc:494, yc:390, xtrans:110, ytrans:198, xother:443, yother:432
dist:39, xa:512, ya:423
   i:0 xb:256, yb:192, D:344.81444, xc:484, yc:397, xtrans:228, ytrans:205, xother:472, yother:405
   i:1 xb:128, yb:244, D:423.67086, xc:477, yc:407, xtrans:349, ytrans:163, xother:460, yother:385
   i:2 xb:192, yb:192, D:394.66568, xc:481, yc:401, xtrans:289, ytrans:209, xother:489, yother:394
   i:3 xb:256, yb:512, D:271.02951, xc:476, yc:435, xtrans:220, ytrans:-77, xother:487, yother:320
   i:4 xb:384, yb:192, D:264.09278, xc:494, yc:389, xtrans:110, ytrans:197, xother:443, yother:431
dist:40, xa:512, ya:423
   i:0 xb:256, yb:192, D:344.81444, xc:483, yc:397, xtrans:227, ytrans:205, xother:471, yother:405
   i:1 xb:128, yb:244, D:423.67086, xc:476, yc:407, xtrans:348, ytrans:163, xother:459, yother:385
   i:2 xb:192, yb:192, D:394.66568, xc:480, yc:400, xtrans:288, ytrans:208, xother:488, yother:393
   i:3 xb:256, yb:512, D:271.02951, xc:475, yc:436, xtrans:219, ytrans:-76, xother:486, yother:321
   i:4 xb:384, yb:192, D:264.09278, xc:493, yc:389, xtrans:109, ytrans:197, xother:442, yother:431
dist:41, xa:512, ya:423
   i:0 xb:256, yb:192, D:344.81444, xc:482, yc:396, xtrans:226, ytrans:204, xother:470, yother:404
   i:1 xb:128, yb:244, D:423.67086, xc:475, yc:406, xtrans:347, ytrans:162, xother:458, yother:384
   i:2 xb:192, yb:192, D:394.66568, xc:479, yc:400, xtrans:287, ytrans:208, xother:487, yother:393
   i:3 xb:256, yb:512, D:271.02951, xc:474, yc:436, xtrans:218, ytrans:-76, xother:485, yother:321
   i:4 xb:384, yb:192, D:264.09278, xc:493, yc:388, xtrans:109, ytrans:196, xother:442, yother:430
dist:42, xa:512, ya:423
   i:0 xb:256, yb:192, D:344.81444, xc:481, yc:395, xtrans:225, ytrans:203, xother:469, yother:403
   i:1 xb:128, yb:244, D:423.67086, xc:474, yc:406, xtrans:346, ytrans:162, xother:457, yother:384
   i:2 xb:192, yb:192, D:394.66568, xc:478, yc:399, xtrans:286, ytrans:207, xother:486, yother:392
   i:3 xb:256, yb:512, D:271.02951, xc:473, yc:436, xtrans:217, ytrans:-76, xother:484, yother:321
   i:4 xb:384, yb:192, D:264.09278, xc:492, yc:387, xtrans:108, ytrans:195, xother:441, yother:429
dist:43, xa:512, ya:423
   i:0 xb:256, yb:192, D:344.81444, xc:481, yc:395, xtrans:225, ytrans:203, xother:469, yother:403
   i:1 xb:128, yb:244, D:423.67086, xc:474, yc:405, xtrans:346, ytrans:161, xother:457, yother:383
   i:2 xb:192, yb:192, D:394.66568, xc:478, yc:398, xtrans:286, ytrans:206, xother:486, yother:391
   i:3 xb:256, yb:512, D:271.02951, xc:472, yc:437, xtrans:216, ytrans:-75, xother:483, yother:322
   i:4 xb:384, yb:192, D:264.09278, xc:492, yc:386, xtrans:108, ytrans:194, xother:441, yother:428
dist:44, xa:512, ya:423
   i:0 xb:256, yb:192, D:344.81444, xc:480, yc:394, xtrans:224, ytrans:202, xother:468, yother:402
   i:1 xb:128, yb:244, D:423.67086, xc:473, yc:405, xtrans:345, ytrans:161, xother:456, yother:383
   i:2 xb:192, yb:192, D:394.66568, xc:477, yc:398, xtrans:285, ytrans:206, xother:485, yother:391
   i:3 xb:256, yb:512, D:271.02951, xc:471, yc:437, xtrans:215, ytrans:-75, xother:482, yother:322
   i:4 xb:384, yb:192, D:264.09278, xc:491, yc:385, xtrans:107, ytrans:193, xother:440, yother:427
dist:45, xa:512, ya:423
   i:0 xb:256, yb:192, D:344.81444, xc:479, yc:393, xtrans:223, ytrans:201, xother:467, yother:401
   i:1 xb:128, yb:244, D:423.67086, xc:472, yc:404, xtrans:344, ytrans:160, xother:455, yother:382
   i:2 xb:192, yb:192, D:394.66568, xc:476, yc:397, xtrans:284, ytrans:205, xother:484, yother:390
   i:3 xb:256, yb:512, D:271.02951, xc:470, yc:437, xtrans:214, ytrans:-75, xother:481, yother:322
   i:4 xb:384, yb:192, D:264.09278, xc:491, yc:384, xtrans:107, ytrans:192, xother:440, yother:426
dist:46, xa:512, ya:423
   i:0 xb:256, yb:192, D:344.81444, xc:478, yc:393, xtrans:222, ytrans:201, xother:466, yother:401
   i:1 xb:128, yb:244, D:423.67086, xc:471, yc:404, xtrans:343, ytrans:160, xother:454, yother:382
   i:2 xb:192, yb:192, D:394.66568, xc:475, yc:397, xtrans:283, ytrans:205, xother:483, yother:390
   i:3 xb:256, yb:512, D:271.02951, xc:469, yc:438, xtrans:213, ytrans:-74, xother:480, yother:323
   i:4 xb:384, yb:192, D:264.09278, xc:490, yc:383, xtrans:106, ytrans:191, xother:439, yother:425
dist:47, xa:512, ya:423
   i:0 xb:256, yb:192, D:344.81444, xc:478, yc:392, xtrans:222, ytrans:200, xother:466, yother:400
   i:1 xb:128, yb:244, D:423.67086, xc:470, yc:404, xtrans:342, ytrans:160, xother:453, yother:382
   i:2 xb:192, yb:192, D:394.66568, xc:474, yc:396, xtrans:282, ytrans:204, xother:482, yother:389
   i:3 xb:256, yb:512, D:271.02951, xc:468, yc:438, xtrans:212, ytrans:-74, xother:479, yother:323
   i:4 xb:384, yb:192, D:264.09278, xc:490, yc:382, xtrans:106, ytrans:190, xother:439, yother:424
dist:48, xa:512, ya:423
   i:0 xb:256, yb:192, D:344.81444, xc:477, yc:391, xtrans:221, ytrans:199, xother:465, yother:399
   i:1 xb:128, yb:244, D:423.67086, xc:469, yc:403, xtrans:341, ytrans:159, xother:452, yother:381
   i:2 xb:192, yb:192, D:394.66568, xc:474, yc:395, xtrans:282, ytrans:203, xother:482, yother:388
   i:3 xb:256, yb:512, D:271.02951, xc:467, yc:438, xtrans:211, ytrans:-74, xother:478, yother:323
   i:4 xb:384, yb:192, D:264.09278, xc:489, yc:382, xtrans:105, ytrans:190, xother:438, yother:424
dist:49, xa:512, ya:423
   i:0 xb:256, yb:192, D:344.81444, xc:476, yc:391, xtrans:220, ytrans:199, xother:464, yother:399
   i:1 xb:128, yb:244, D:423.67086, xc:468, yc:403, xtrans:340, ytrans:159, xother:451, yother:381
   i:2 xb:192, yb:192, D:394.66568, xc:473, yc:395, xtrans:281, ytrans:203, xother:481, yother:388
   i:3 xb:256, yb:512, D:271.02951, xc:466, yc:439, xtrans:210, ytrans:-73, xother:477, yother:324
   i:4 xb:384, yb:192, D:264.09278, xc:489, yc:381, xtrans:105, ytrans:189, xother:438, yother:423
dist:50, xa:512, ya:423
   i:0 xb:256, yb:192, D:344.81444, xc:475, yc:390, xtrans:219, ytrans:198, xother:463, yother:398
   i:1 xb:128, yb:244, D:423.67086, xc:467, yc:402, xtrans:339, ytrans:158, xother:450, yother:380
   i:2 xb:192, yb:192, D:394.66568, xc:472, yc:394, xtrans:280, ytrans:202, xother:480, yother:387
   i:3 xb:256, yb:512, D:271.02951, xc:465, yc:439, xtrans:209, ytrans:-73, xother:476, yother:324
   i:4 xb:384, yb:192, D:264.09278, xc:488, yc:380, xtrans:104, ytrans:188, xother:437, yother:422
dist:51, xa:512, ya:423
   i:0 xb:256, yb:192, D:344.81444, xc:475, yc:389, xtrans:219, ytrans:197, xother:463, yother:397
   i:1 xb:128, yb:244, D:423.67086, xc:466, yc:402, xtrans:338, ytrans:158, xother:449, yother:380
   i:2 xb:192, yb:192, D:394.66568, xc:471, yc:394, xtrans:279, ytrans:202, xother:479, yother:387
   i:3 xb:256, yb:512, D:271.02951, xc:464, yc:439, xtrans:208, ytrans:-73, xother:475, yother:324
   i:4 xb:384, yb:192, D:264.09278, xc:488, yc:379, xtrans:104, ytrans:187, xother:437, yother:421
dist:52, xa:512, ya:423
   i:0 xb:256, yb:192, D:344.81444, xc:474, yc:389, xtrans:218, ytrans:197, xother:462, yother:397
   i:1 xb:128, yb:244, D:423.67086, xc:465, yc:402, xtrans:337, ytrans:158, xother:448, yother:380
   i:2 xb:192, yb:192, D:394.66568, xc:470, yc:393, xtrans:278, ytrans:201, xother:478, yother:386
   i:3 xb:256, yb:512, D:271.02951, xc:463, yc:440, xtrans:207, ytrans:-72, xother:474, yother:325
   i:4 xb:384, yb:192, D:264.09278, xc:487, yc:378, xtrans:103, ytrans:186, xother:436, yother:420
dist:53, xa:512, ya:423
   i:0 xb:256, yb:192, D:344.81444, xc:473, yc:388, xtrans:217, ytrans:196, xother:461, yother:396
   i:1 xb:128, yb:244, D:423.67086, xc:464, yc:401, xtrans:336, ytrans:157, xother:447, yother:379
   i:2 xb:192, yb:192, D:394.66568, xc:470, yc:392, xtrans:278, ytrans:200, xother:478, yother:385
   i:3 xb:256, yb:512, D:271.02951, xc:462, yc:440, xtrans:206, ytrans:-72, xother:473, yother:325
   i:4 xb:384, yb:192, D:264.09278, xc:487, yc:377, xtrans:103, ytrans:185, xother:436, yother:419
dist:54, xa:512, ya:423
   i:0 xb:256, yb:192, D:344.81444, xc:472, yc:387, xtrans:216, ytrans:195, xother:460, yother:395
   i:1 xb:128, yb:244, D:423.67086, xc:464, yc:401, xtrans:336, ytrans:157, xother:447, yother:379
   i:2 xb:192, yb:192, D:394.66568, xc:469, yc:392, xtrans:277, ytrans:200, xother:477, yother:385
   i:3 xb:256, yb:512, D:271.02951, xc:461, yc:440, xtrans:205, ytrans:-72, xother:472, yother:325
   i:4 xb:384, yb:192, D:264.09278, xc:486, yc:376, xtrans:102, ytrans:184, xother:435, yother:418
dist:55, xa:512, ya:423
   i:0 xb:256, yb:192, D:344.81444, xc:472, yc:387, xtrans:216, ytrans:195, xother:460, yother:395
   i:1 xb:128, yb:244, D:423.67086, xc:463, yc:400, xtrans:335, ytrans:156, xother:446, yother:378
   i:2 xb:192, yb:192, D:394.66568, xc:468, yc:391, xtrans:276, ytrans:199, xother:476, yother:384
   i:3 xb:256, yb:512, D:271.02951, xc:461, yc:441, xtrans:205, ytrans:-71, xother:472, yother:326
   i:4 xb:384, yb:192, D:264.09278, xc:486, yc:375, xtrans:102, ytrans:183, xother:435, yother:417
dist:56, xa:512, ya:423
   i:0 xb:256, yb:192, D:344.81444, xc:471, yc:386, xtrans:215, ytrans:194, xother:459, yother:394
   i:1 xb:128, yb:244, D:423.67086, xc:462, yc:400, xtrans:334, ytrans:156, xother:445, yother:378
   i:2 xb:192, yb:192, D:394.66568, xc:467, yc:391, xtrans:275, ytrans:199, xother:475, yother:384
   i:3 xb:256, yb:512, D:271.02951, xc:460, yc:441, xtrans:204, ytrans:-71, xother:471, yother:326
   i:4 xb:384, yb:192, D:264.09278, xc:485, yc:375, xtrans:101, ytrans:183, xother:434, yother:417
dist:57, xa:512, ya:423
   i:0 xb:256, yb:192, D:344.81444, xc:470, yc:385, xtrans:214, ytrans:193, xother:458, yother:393
   i:1 xb:128, yb:244, D:423.67086, xc:461, yc:399, xtrans:333, ytrans:155, xother:444, yother:377
   i:2 xb:192, yb:192, D:394.66568, xc:466, yc:390, xtrans:274, ytrans:198, xother:474, yother:383
   i:3 xb:256, yb:512, D:271.02951, xc:459, yc:441, xtrans:203, ytrans:-71, xother:470, yother:326
   i:4 xb:384, yb:192, D:264.09278, xc:485, yc:374, xtrans:101, ytrans:182, xother:434, yother:416
dist:58, xa:512, ya:423
   i:0 xb:256, yb:192, D:344.81444, xc:469, yc:385, xtrans:213, ytrans:193, xother:457, yother:393
   i:1 xb:128, yb:244, D:423.67086, xc:460, yc:399, xtrans:332, ytrans:155, xother:443, yother:377
   i:2 xb:192, yb:192, D:394.66568, xc:465, yc:390, xtrans:273, ytrans:198, xother:473, yother:383
   i:3 xb:256, yb:512, D:271.02951, xc:458, yc:442, xtrans:202, ytrans:-70, xother:469, yother:327
   i:4 xb:384, yb:192, D:264.09278, xc:484, yc:373, xtrans:100, ytrans:181, xother:433, yother:415
dist:59, xa:512, ya:423
   i:0 xb:256, yb:192, D:344.81444, xc:469, yc:384, xtrans:213, ytrans:192, xother:457, yother:392
   i:1 xb:128, yb:244, D:423.67086, xc:459, yc:399, xtrans:331, ytrans:155, xother:442, yother:377
   i:2 xb:192, yb:192, D:394.66568, xc:465, yc:389, xtrans:273, ytrans:197, xother:473, yother:382
   i:3 xb:256, yb:512, D:271.02951, xc:457, yc:442, xtrans:201, ytrans:-70, xother:468, yother:327
   i:4 xb:384, yb:192, D:264.09278, xc:484, yc:372, xtrans:100, ytrans:180, xother:433, yother:414
dist:60, xa:512, ya:423
   i:0 xb:256, yb:192, D:344.81444, xc:468, yc:383, xtrans:212, ytrans:191, xother:456, yother:391
   i:1 xb:128, yb:244, D:423.67086, xc:458, yc:398, xtrans:330, ytrans:154, xother:441, yother:376
   i:2 xb:192, yb:192, D:394.66568, xc:464, yc:388, xtrans:272, ytrans:196, xother:472, yother:381
   i:3 xb:256, yb:512, D:271.02951, xc:456, yc:442, xtrans:200, ytrans:-70, xother:467, yother:327
   i:4 xb:384, yb:192, D:264.09278, xc:483, yc:371, xtrans:99, ytrans:179, xother:432, yother:413
dist:61, xa:512, ya:423
   i:0 xb:256, yb:192, D:344.81444, xc:467, yc:383, xtrans:211, ytrans:191, xother:455, yother:391
   i:1 xb:128, yb:244, D:423.67086, xc:457, yc:398, xtrans:329, ytrans:154, xother:440, yother:376
   i:2 xb:192, yb:192, D:394.66568, xc:463, yc:388, xtrans:271, ytrans:196, xother:471, yother:381
   i:3 xb:256, yb:512, D:271.02951, xc:455, yc:443, xtrans:199, ytrans:-69, xother:466, yother:328
   i:4 xb:384, yb:192, D:264.09278, xc:483, yc:370, xtrans:99, ytrans:178, xother:432, yother:412
dist:62, xa:512, ya:423
   i:0 xb:256, yb:192, D:344.81444, xc:466, yc:382, xtrans:210, ytrans:190, xother:454, yother:390
   i:1 xb:128, yb:244, D:423.67086, xc:456, yc:397, xtrans:328, ytrans:153, xother:439, yother:375
   i:2 xb:192, yb:192, D:394.66568, xc:462, yc:387, xtrans:270, ytrans:195, xother:470, yother:380
   i:3 xb:256, yb:512, D:271.02951, xc:454, yc:443, xtrans:198, ytrans:-69, xother:465, yother:328
   i:4 xb:384, yb:192, D:264.09278, xc:482, yc:369, xtrans:98, ytrans:177, xother:431, yother:411
dist:63, xa:512, ya:423
   i:0 xb:256, yb:192, D:344.81444, xc:466, yc:381, xtrans:210, ytrans:189, xother:454, yother:389
   i:1 xb:128, yb:244, D:423.67086, xc:455, yc:397, xtrans:327, ytrans:153, xother:438, yother:375
   i:2 xb:192, yb:192, D:394.66568, xc:461, yc:387, xtrans:269, ytrans:195, xother:469, yother:380
   i:3 xb:256, yb:512, D:271.02951, xc:453, yc:443, xtrans:197, ytrans:-69, xother:464, yother:328
   i:4 xb:384, yb:192, D:264.09278, xc:482, yc:368, xtrans:98, ytrans:176, xother:431, yother:410
dist:64, xa:512, ya:423
   i:0 xb:256, yb:192, D:344.81444, xc:465, yc:381, xtrans:209, ytrans:189, xother:453, yother:389
   i:1 xb:128, yb:244, D:423.67086, xc:454, yc:396, xtrans:326, ytrans:152, xother:437, yother:374
   i:2 xb:192, yb:192, D:394.66568, xc:461, yc:386, xtrans:269, ytrans:194, xother:469, yother:379
   i:3 xb:256, yb:512, D:271.02951, xc:452, yc:444, xtrans:196, ytrans:-68, xother:463, yother:329
   i:4 xb:384, yb:192, D:264.09278, xc:481, yc:368, xtrans:97, ytrans:176, xother:430, yother:410
dist:65, xa:512, ya:423
   i:0 xb:256, yb:192, D:344.81444, xc:464, yc:380, xtrans:208, ytrans:188, xother:452, yother:388
   i:1 xb:128, yb:244, D:423.67086, xc:454, yc:396, xtrans:326, ytrans:152, xother:437, yother:374
   i:2 xb:192, yb:192, D:394.66568, xc:460, yc:385, xtrans:268, ytrans:193, xother:468, yother:378
   i:3 xb:256, yb:512, D:271.02951, xc:451, yc:444, xtrans:195, ytrans:-68, xother:462, yother:329
   i:4 xb:384, yb:192, D:264.09278, xc:481, yc:367, xtrans:97, ytrans:175, xother:430, yother:409
dist:66, xa:512, ya:423
   i:0 xb:256, yb:192, D:344.81444, xc:463, yc:379, xtrans:207, ytrans:187, xother:451, yother:387
   i:1 xb:128, yb:244, D:423.67086, xc:453, yc:396, xtrans:325, ytrans:152, xother:436, yother:374
   i:2 xb:192, yb:192, D:394.66568, xc:459, yc:385, xtrans:267, ytrans:193, xother:467, yother:378
   i:3 xb:256, yb:512, D:271.02951, xc:450, yc:444, xtrans:194, ytrans:-68, xother:461, yother:329
   i:4 xb:384, yb:192, D:264.09278, xc:481, yc:366, xtrans:97, ytrans:174, xother:430, yother:408
dist:67, xa:512, ya:423
   i:0 xb:256, yb:192, D:344.81444, xc:463, yc:379, xtrans:207, ytrans:187, xother:451, yother:387
   i:1 xb:128, yb:244, D:423.67086, xc:452, yc:395, xtrans:324, ytrans:151, xother:435, yother:373
   i:2 xb:192, yb:192, D:394.66568, xc:458, yc:384, xtrans:266, ytrans:192, xother:466, yother:377
   i:3 xb:256, yb:512, D:271.02951, xc:449, yc:445, xtrans:193, ytrans:-67, xother:460, yother:330
   i:4 xb:384, yb:192, D:264.09278, xc:480, yc:365, xtrans:96, ytrans:173, xother:429, yother:407
dist:68, xa:512, ya:423
   i:0 xb:256, yb:192, D:344.81444, xc:462, yc:378, xtrans:206, ytrans:186, xother:450, yother:386
   i:1 xb:128, yb:244, D:423.67086, xc:451, yc:395, xtrans:323, ytrans:151, xother:434, yother:373
   i:2 xb:192, yb:192, D:394.66568, xc:457, yc:384, xtrans:265, ytrans:192, xother:465, yother:377
   i:3 xb:256, yb:512, D:271.02951, xc:448, yc:445, xtrans:192, ytrans:-67, xother:459, yother:330
   i:4 xb:384, yb:192, D:264.09278, xc:480, yc:364, xtrans:96, ytrans:172, xother:429, yother:406
dist:69, xa:512, ya:423
   i:0 xb:256, yb:192, D:344.81444, xc:461, yc:377, xtrans:205, ytrans:185, xother:449, yother:385
   i:1 xb:128, yb:244, D:423.67086, xc:450, yc:394, xtrans:322, ytrans:150, xother:433, yother:372
   i:2 xb:192, yb:192, D:394.66568, xc:457, yc:383, xtrans:265, ytrans:191, xother:465, yother:376
   i:3 xb:256, yb:512, D:271.02951, xc:447, yc:445, xtrans:191, ytrans:-67, xother:458, yother:330
   i:4 xb:384, yb:192, D:264.09278, xc:479, yc:363, xtrans:95, ytrans:171, xother:428, yother:405
dist:70, xa:512, ya:423
   i:0 xb:256, yb:192, D:344.81444, xc:461, yc:377, xtrans:205, ytrans:185, xother:449, yother:385
   i:1 xb:128, yb:244, D:423.67086, xc:449, yc:394, xtrans:321, ytrans:150, xother:432, yother:372
   i:2 xb:192, yb:192, D:394.66568, xc:456, yc:383, xtrans:264, ytrans:191, xother:464, yother:376
   i:3 xb:256, yb:512, D:271.02951, xc:446, yc:445, xtrans:190, ytrans:-67, xother:457, yother:330
   i:4 xb:384, yb:192, D:264.09278, xc:479, yc:362, xtrans:95, ytrans:170, xother:428, yother:404
```

I have also plotted an image with `pointa` coordinates getting progressively redder as you go through the array, and `pointb` getting progressively bluer as you go through the array and the centre in white. However, I am absolutely none the wiser about what you are trying to do!

```
convert -size 600x600 xc:black -fill white -draw "circle 512,423 512,428" \
   -fill "rgba(255,0,0,0.6)" -draw "circle 256,192 256,197" \
   -fill "rgba(255,0,0,0.7)" -draw "circle 128,244 128,249" \
   -fill "rgba(255,0,0,0.8)" -draw "circle 192,192 192,197" \
   -fill "rgba(255,0,0,0.9)" -draw "circle 256,512 256,517" \
   -fill "rgba(255,0,0,1.0)" -draw "circle 384,192 384,197" \
   -fill "rgba(0,0,255,0.6)" -draw "circle 244,200 244,205" \
   -fill "rgba(0,0,255,0.7)" -draw "circle 111,222 111,227" \
   -fill "rgba(0,0,255,0.8)" -draw "circle 200,185 200,190" \
   -fill "rgba(0,0,255,0.9)" -draw "circle 267,397 267,402" \
   -fill "rgba(0,0,255,1.0)" -draw "circle 333,234 333,239" \
   image.png
```

[image]